# Why do people specify date as an option for \usepackage?

Tags: packages, optional-arguments, package-options, latex-base

In LaTeX code written by other people, I sometimes see a date specified as an optional argument for `\usepackage`:

```
\usepackage{iftex}[2013/04/04]
```

Intuition tells me that this is some way to ensure that the package version meets a certain minimal requirement, but I would like to read about its usage in the official manual, as opposed to blindly paste it in my code based on guesswork.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From `source2e.pdf`, page 479 ([CTAN page](https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en) or `texdoc source2e` in a terminal):

> [image: <code>\usepackage[<package-option-list>]{<package-list>}[<version>]</code>//There can be any number of these declarations. All packages in <code><package-list></code> are called with the same options.//Each <code><package></code> file defines new elements (or modifies those defined in the <code><class></code>), and thus extends the range of documents which can be processed. The <code><package-option-list></code> is a list of options which can modify the formatting of elements defined in the <code><package></code> file. The <code><version></code> is a version number, beginning with a date in the format <code>YYYY/MM/DD</code>. If an older version of the package is found, a warning is issued.]

Comment: Perfect. (I guess I failed to find it myself because of the non-obvious name of the manual file).

Comment: @ScumCoder There are probably other documents saying this :) (sorry, but 7 what?)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik we should update that documentation.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ooh, Frank's format :)

Answer (score 11):

Phelype Oleinik pointed you at the LaTeX sources but there is also a user guide called `usrguide.pdf`

```
 texdoc usrguide
```

will open the document in texlive. Section 3.2 on preamble commands has the syntax for `\usepackage`.

This argument was extended with new syntax last year so you may also want to look at LaTeX News 28 in `texdoc ltnews` which points you at this article from TUGBoat on the project website

https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-FMi-TUB-tb122mitt-version-rollback.pdf

Comment: How can I access the `usrguide.pdf` document from MiKTeX?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth no idea about miktex, I assume it has some option equivalent to texdoc, but the document is available from multiple places on the net eg https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/usrguide.pdf

Comment: Unable to determine the miktex option, but found the document.

Comment: I'm told texdoc should work in miktex just as in texlive.

Comment: Just noticed that for `texdoc url`, `texdoc siunitx` etc. plugged in at the command prompt MiKTeX delivers the goods as expected. `texdoc usrguide` seems to be the one exception. Perhaps the document goes by another name?